# Calculating with integers and floating point numbers using c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main () 
{
 int a, b;

 printf("Please type in your number a: ");
 scanf_s("%d", &a);

 printf("Please type in your number b: ");
 scanf_s("%d", &b);

 printf("Solution 1 (divide and modulus): %f\n", a / b +  a % b); 
 printf("Solution 2 (cast): %f", (float) a / b); 

 std::cin.get(); 
 std::cin.get(); 

 return 0;

}
```

I want my program to read two integers and i want to use two different methods to divide them without round-off errors. Sincerly the first solution does not work. The output are just zeros. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Apart from your problem which has already been adequately addressed, I wonder why are you using both <cstdio> and <iostream>. Try to be stylistically consistent, giving a huge preference to the latter choice. IMHO :)

Comment: And even using `stdio.h` instead of the correct `cstdio`

Comment: Just stick to one of the two languages when learning. There is no such thing like C/C++. If you want to learn C++ use `iostream` etc and compile with a C++ compiler. If you learn C, use `stdio.h` and compile with a C compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `a/b + a%b` is an `integer` (`%d`), but you are printing out a `float` (`%f`).

Comment: Yes. Now i understand where my mistake was. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be:

```
a/b + (a%b)/(float)b
```

Comment: type-casting any of the variable with float will cause all the variables to be floats n the output would be a float , not an int.

Comment: Yes, but since he is printing a float (%f) I though that his formula may just be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
 printf("Solution 1 (divide and modulus): %f\n", a / b +  a % b);
```

to

```
 printf("Solution 1 divide %i modulus %i \n", a / b,  a % b);
```